# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in

Tags: php

```
function get($a,$b,$c) {

    $y = explode($b,$a);
    $x = explode($c,$y[1]);

    return $x[0];
}
```

returns error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do you call your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question

Comment: If your variables are _really_ called a, b and c, you need to rename them. It's not clear that you have put the parameters into `explode` correctly. The first parameter is a delimiter string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$y[1]` isn't set.

You need to check there's a value before running it through explode.

```
$y = explode( $b, $a );

if ( isset( $y[1] ) ) {
    $x = explode( $c, $y[1] );
    return ( isset( $x[0] ) ) ? $x[0] : '';
} else {
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning that says array key is not set.

You can use php's related function whether a specific array key exists or not.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

This function will help you.